# Prevent re-entrant function call in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, locking

The purpose of this is to prevent a re-entrant function call in a single thread, e.g. prevent the situation where `func()` calls `bar()` which calls `func()`.

This is currently not used in any multithreaded code (and does not plan to be).

```
struct TranLock
{
static int count;
    bool failed;
    TranLock() { failed = count; if (!failed) ++count; }
    ~TranLock() { if (!failed) --count; }
};
int TranLock::count = 0;
```

Usage:

```
void func()
{
    TranLock lock;
    if ( lock.failed )
        return;   // or take other action

    // the function's logic here
}
```

Is there a better idiom for this, e.g. involving `std::shared_ptr` ? C++11 features OK.

**Update:** As pointed out by Greg Hewgill, if multiple functions use `TranLock` they will all have a shared lockout. Currently I only use it in one function, although it would be nice to see two different possible implementations:

- Lock which can be shared amongst functions
- Individual lock per function

(perhaps this could be controlled with a template parameter or something).

Comment: Why not just a static variable inside the function?

Comment: That's really messy , RAII is essential

Answer (score 11):

The obvious problem with this is it will detect any function that uses `TranLock` calling any other function that also uses `TranLock` (since there is only a single global `count`). That is, if `func()` (which uses `TranLock`) calls `bar()` (which also uses `TranLock`) then `bar()` will erroneously fail.

In order to make a lock like this that can be used with multiple functions, create a class with *no* static members, then in each function where you want to use a lock, create a `static` instance of the class. That way, each function will have its own independent counter. However, you can't rely on the class destructor in this case because the destructor of static objects is not called when the object goes out of scope.

You could use a hybrid of these two techniques, for example

```
struct TranLock
{
    int &count;
    TranLock(int &count): count(count) { failed = count; if (!failed) ++count; }
    ~TranLock() { if (!failed) --count; }
};

void func()
{
    static int TranLock_count;
    TranLock lock(TranLock_count);
    if (lock.failed) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, you don't really need to maintain an `int count` at all. Since you only ever increment `count` when it is zero, a `bool` flag would do equally well.

Answer (score 0):

How about: - or just use a mutex.aquire() instead of the bool and you're threadsafe.

```
class lock
{
    bool &b_;

public:
    lock( bool &b )
      : b_( b )
    {
        if( b ) throw reentry_exception;
        b = true;
    }
    ~lock()
    {
        b = false;
    }
};

static bool func_running = false;
void func()
{
    lock mylock = lock( func_running );
}
```

Comment: Sorry - my mistake! The lock object should of course be initialized on the stack, without new!

Comment: A mutex is not appropriate because the OP asked for a way to *prevent a re-entrant function call in a single thread*.

Comment: @GregHewgill That depends on the mutex-implementation used, there are some mutexes which will allow any number of acquires by the same thread and some mutexes which will only allow one acquire by any thread - so they will work the same for single and multi-threaded!

Comment: Yes, that's true, but neither of those options will do what the original question asked for - one kind of mutex will ignore recursive calls on the same thread and the other kind will deadlock.